# TypeError: jQuery(“#mycarousel”).jcarousel is not a function

Tags: 7, javascript

I added this jQuery function to my drupal7 header for jcorousel plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({wrap: "circular"});
        jQuery("#mycarousel img").tooltip();
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

However, this didn't work and I see this error in firebug panel:

```
TypeError: jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel is not a function
 jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({wrap: "circular"});
```

I'm not sure how to fix this error and make my function work as supposed to.

**NOTE:** Add Plugin In->`sites/all/themes/mytheme/theme.info` this line => `scripts[] = js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js` this plugin included in my header, i see this.

**EDIT:** I Clear Cache From Admin Panel(`admin/config/development/performance`) And Fix This Error.

Comment: Check whether that script is included in the page by viewing the page source, additional note try clearing the cache.

Comment: where did you print `$scripts` in theme ? at the bottom?

Comment: @Mathankumar +1. I clear Cache and fix this error. Thanks